# Cholesky decomposition in c fails

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm fairly new to c and wanted to implement the cholesky decomposition according to the pseudo code from wikipedia.
It is required, that the ram is allocated dynamically.

I tried my code with the following example matrix:

```
 4.000  2.000  0.000  0.000
 2.000  5.000  2.000  0.000
 0.000  2.000 10.000  3.000
 0.000  0.000  3.000  2.000
```

which should result in:

```
2.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
1.000 2.000 0.000 0.000
0.000 1.000 3.000 0.000
0.000 0.000 1.000 1.000
```

But instead returns me.

```
4.000 2.000 0.000  0.000 
0.000 5.000 2.000  0.000 
0.000 0.000 10.000 3.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000  2.000
```

I guess I have something misunderstood in using the pointers. I tried to allocate dynamically according to [this link](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/c_von_a_bis_z/014_c_dyn_speicherverwaltung_011.htm).

Can anybody tell me, why the correct values are not written into my matrix?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int Cholesky(int n, double **A){
    double sum;
    sum = 0.0f;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < j-1; k++)
            {
                sum = sum - A[i][k]*A[j][k];
            }
            if(i > j)
            {
                A[i][j] = sum / A[j][j];
            } else
            {
                if(sum > 0)
                {
                    A[i][i] = sqrt(sum);
                } else {
                    printf("Die Matrix ist nicht symetrisch positiv\n");
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%.5f ", A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }

}

int main(){
    int n = 4;
    double ** matrix;

    double test[4][4] = {{4.0f,2.0f,0.0f,0.0f},{2.0f,5.0f,2.0f,0.0f},{0.0f,2.0f,10.0f, 3.0f},{0.0f,0.0f,3.0f,2.0f}};

    /* Speicher reservieren für die int-Zeiger (=zeile) */
    matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
    if(NULL == matrix) {
       printf("Kein virtueller RAM mehr vorhanden ... !");
       return -1;
    }
    /* jetzt noch Speicher reservieren für die einzelnen Spalten
     * der i-ten Zeile */
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
        if(NULL == matrix[i]) {
            printf("Kein Speicher mehr fuer Zeile %d\n",i);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    /* mit beliebigen Werten initialisieren */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = test[i][j];

    /* Inhalt der Matrix entsprechend ausgeben */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%.5f ", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }

    Cholesky(n, matrix);

    /* Spalten der i-ten Zeile freigeben */
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);
    /* Jetzt können die leeren Zeilen freigegeben werden. */
    free(matrix);
    int x;
    scanf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sum is uninitialised.

Comment: @terrence-hill, what did the compiler do that it returns the original matrix and not a garbage matrix? Unitialized `sum` will cause undefined behavior; did the compiler just skip all calculations with `sum`? That is, skip the whole `for` loop?

Comment: Okay, I initialized sum now by double sum; sum = 0.0f; but still no values are written to my matrix.

Comment: @Paul Ogilive I can't see malloc errors so I pointed out the error i saw. If you change the value of sum from 0 to 100 you will see that the matrix values change. I suspect an error in the algorithm.

Comment: `if(i > j)` is invariant/true, caused by `for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)` Typo?

Comment: @Joop, good catch, but still `A[i][i] = sqrt(sum);` is peformed, which should change the matrix.

Comment: Igle, did you see the matrix is printed twice, once the original and what does the second look like? Unchanged?

Comment: What wikipedia pseudocode are you referring to? The only pseudocode I see in the primary article is for Rank-one update.

Comment: `4.00000 2.00000 0.00000 0.00000 
2.00000 5.00000 2.00000 0.00000 
0.00000 2.00000 10.00000 3.00000 
0.00000 0.00000 3.00000 2.00000` <hr/>
`4.00000 2.00000 0.00000 0.00000 
0.00000 5.00000 2.00000 0.00000 
0.00000 0.00000 10.00000 3.00000 
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 2.00000`

Comment: I've submitted a correction for the question because in fact, the array is modified (as you can see in my prev comment) just not correctly. Awaiting peer review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamically allocated matrix is correct and also the use of pointers.

The correct values are not written into your matrix because the algorithm you employed for the cholesky decomposition is wrong. You can find the correct algorithm for example here:

http://www2.denizyuret.com/bib/press/www.library.cornell.edu/nr/bookcpdf/c2-9.pdf

Your function only modify the matrix at this instruction:

```
if (i > j) A[i][j] = sum / A[j][j];
```

which means that the elements below the diagonal are zeroed, as shown in your post.

```
4.000 2.000 0.000  0.000 
0.000 5.000 2.000  0.000 
0.000 0.000 10.000 3.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000  2.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You print the matrix before calling Cholesky(), that is why the original matrix is printed.

Comment: Good catch but even if the dump is moved to the right place, same problem

Comment: He prints it once before calling Cholesy, and once in Cholesky after processing the matrix. The second one should be the changed matrix.

Answer (score -1):

Does Cholesky algorithm work in-place?

try using this as the basis for your function

```
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        chol[i][i] = A[i][i];
        for (int k=0; k<i; k++)
            chol[i][i] -= chol[k][i]*chol[k][i];
        chol[i][i] = sqrt(chol[i][i]);
        for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
            chol[i][j] = A[i][j];
            for (k=0; k<i; k++)
                chol[i][j] -= chol[k][i]*chol[k][j];
            chol[i][j] /= chol[i][i];
        }
 }
```

Comment: Does this solve his problem? What was his problem? His code looks OK to me (assuming Cholesky method is implemented correctly).

Comment: No. The Cholesky algoithm is not implemented correctly.

Answer (score -1):

so for example, since I hate arrays of arrays:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>

#define idx(A,i,j) A[i*n+j]

void Cholesky(int n, double *A)
{
    double *chol = (double *)calloc(sizeof(double) * n * n, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        idx(chol, i, i) = idx(A, i, i);
        for (int k = 0; k<i; k++)
            idx(chol, i, i) -= idx(chol, k, i) * idx(chol, k, i);
        idx(chol, i, i) = sqrt(idx(chol, i, i));
        for (int j = i + 1; j<n; j++) {
            idx(chol, i, j) = idx(A, i, j);
            for (int k = 0; k<i; k++)
                idx(chol, i, j) -= idx(chol, k, i) * idx(chol, k, j);
            idx(chol, i, j) /= idx(chol, i, i);
        }
    }

    memcpy(A, chol, sizeof(double) * n * n);
    free(chol);
}

int main()
{
    double test[] = { 
        4.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        2.0f, 5.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 2.0f, 10.0f, 3.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f };

    Cholesky(4, test);
}
```

Comment: Does this solve his problem? What was his problem? His code looks OK to me (assuming Cholesky method is implemented correctly).

Comment: Yes. It solves his problem in that it is a correct implementation whereas his is quite buggy

Comment: Several which is why I provided simple and correct pseudocode and actual working code. For example of a bug, sum should be initialized with the next diagonal value of the matrix at each loop i.e. sum = A[i][i]. The correct loops and assignments are clearly described in my answer which has been downvoted for some reason.

Comment: I also don't think the algorithm works "in place" so this implementation is clobbering the source while computing the result.